# how to filter <EnumRadioGroup> options from Constants in Blazor Project

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, ant-design-blazor

I want to filter the options based on the constants. But it keeps showing the full list of the constants.

I have tried coded this way:

```
<EnumRadioGroup
    TEnum="@ConceptConstants.MaritalStatus"
    @bind-Value="@context.Status"
    Options="GetFilteredMaritalStatusOptions">
</EnumRadioGroup>
```

```
protected IEnumerable<MaritalStatus> GetFilteredMaritalStatusOptions()
{
    return Enum
        .GetValues(typeof(MaritalStatus))
        .Cast<MaritalStatus>()
        .Where(status => status == MaritalStatus.Married || status == MaritalStatus.Single);
}
```

but is show me this error ->:

> Cant convert from "method group" to `oneof.oneof <string[], antdesign radio option <Constance.ConceptConatst.MartialStatus>`

Comment: `EnumRadioGroup` is not a standard Blazor control.

Comment: ahh yea im using ant-design-blazor component. may i know if you know how to filter the option out?

Comment: From what I can tell, `Options` needs to be an `IEnumerable<RadioOption<TEnum>>`: https://github.com/ant-design-blazor/ant-design-blazor/blob/master/components/radio/EnumRadioGroup.cs

Comment: ermm.. somehow not working thanks btw!